# UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment within comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.8, dictionary-comprehension

I'm playing around with `dict` comprehensions, and trying [PEP572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) (the `:=` operator), in an example like this:

```py
columns = {'idx', 'class_name'}
# populate them somehow
# ...
retval = {names[idx]:idx for idx in range(len(names)) if (names := list(columns))}
```

So basically, a `dict` that contains the item in the `set` and a value that iterates over it.
However, `names` seems to be an `UnboundLocalError`.

The below is what I'm trying to do, capture an alias of an outside variable of the scope of the comprehension:

```
names = list(columns)
retval = {names[idx]:idx for idx in range(len(names))}
```

Why is that an error?

## Edit

Trying this within the captured `columns`:

```
retval = {names[idx]:idx for idx in range(len(names:= list(columns)))}
```

produced a more meaningful IMHO error:

```
SyntaxError: assignment expression cannot be used in a comprehension iterable expression
```

So, as answered below, this isn't the way in which the walrus operator is meant to be used.

Comment: ... obviously the `if` part is evaluated after the `for` part (otherwise what is there to filter on?), right?

Comment: In your first code, you have never deifned a variable called names so the execution of  range(len(names)) will fail as there is no vaiable called names

Comment: Can you please clarify what you think the first code is even supposed to do?

Comment: You could produce the same result with a much simpler comprehension `retval1 = {val: index for index, val in enumerate(columns)}`

Comment: Just a side note, I think that if the `:=` is done in the first usage of the `name` (which is in the `range(len(names))` part) it would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misusing the condition. It is evaluated once per value retrieved from the iterator; it cannot be used to *define* the iterator. `names` isn't yet defined when you try to evaluate `len(names)`.

Using `range` when you could use `enumerate` is a bit of anti-pattern anyway; try

```
retval = {name: idx for idx, name in enumerate(columns)}
```

Note that `columns` doesn't have a reliable ordering anyway; sets do not preserve the order in which items are added like `dict`s do.

Comment: so the operator `:=` doesn't define new local variables within the scope of the comprehension, it's more of an alias?

Comment: It does, but the semantics are different than for a assignment statement, because it's an ordinary expression.

Comment: (Even if it were like an assignment statement, it would still be undefined, even if it were marked as *going* to be local.)

Comment: AFAIK the iterated variable within a comprehension is the only visible variable outside the scope of the comprehension, thus I understood the assignment as possible because of that. I guess I'm wrong, the assignment is only accepted within the comprehension's scope.

Comment: The iterated variable *might* be visible, but that's just a matter of whether it is a free variable or not. E.g., `[z for y in x for z in y]`: `x` is a free variable, so either has a value outside the comprehension or a `NameError` is raised. `y` is iterated over, but is local to the list comprehension. `:=` simply creates a new name in the scope, when and if the expression is evaluated. (The same for `=`, really, except the mere presence of an `=` is enough to shadow a global variable, whether or not the local name is ever defined.)